# override OnActionExecuting by HttpActionContext in .NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, model, asp.net-core-webapi, actioncontext

I have a old MVC program web api with [ValidateModel] attribute:

```
[Route("login")]
[ValidateModel]
public User Login(LoginModel model)
{

}
```

Validate the model by code below and return with custom response:

```
public class ValidateModelAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        if (!actionContext.ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateResponse(
                    HttpStatusCode.BadRequest,
                    new CustomErrorResult
                    {
                        Succeeded = false,
                        Errors = actionContext.ModelState.Values.SelectMany(
                            o => o.Errors.Select(
                                e => e.ErrorMessage))
                    });
        }

        base.OnActionExecuting(actionContext);
    }
}
```

Custom error result class

```
public class CustomErrorResult
{
    public bool Succeeded { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<string> Errors { get; set; }
}
```

I am revamping the code to .NET Core now, how do I modify this part to Core version?

I am researched quite some time but still unable solve this, .NET Core seem have a feature can suppress custom response in startup/program file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using a controller with the `[ApiController]` attribute applied, ASP.NET Core automatically handles model validation errors by returning a 400 Bad Request with `ModelState` as the response body.

Reference: [Automatic HTTP 400 responses](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/?view=aspnetcore-6.0#automatic-http-400-responses)

**One way** is that you could suppress this feature by:

```
services.AddControllers().ConfigureApiBehaviorOptions(options => {
    options.SuppressModelStateInvalidFilter = true;
});
```

And change your custom ValidateModel:

```
public class ValidateModelAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        if (!context.ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            context.Result = new BadRequestObjectResult(new CustomErrorResult
            {
                Succeeded = false,
                Errors = context.ModelState.Values.SelectMany(
                            o => o.Errors.Select(
                                e => e.ErrorMessage))
            });               
            
        }

        base.OnActionExecuting(context);
    }
}
```

**Another way without customizing ValidateModel** is to use a custom response factory in Startup.cs like below:

```
services.Configure<ApiBehaviorOptions>(o =>
{
    o.InvalidModelStateResponseFactory = actionContext =>
        new BadRequestObjectResult(new BadRequestObjectResult(new CustomErrorResult
        {
            Succeeded = false,
            Errors = actionContext.ModelState.Values.SelectMany(
                    o => o.Errors.Select(
                        e => e.ErrorMessage))
        }));
});
```